# datetime -doctrine results by start to end date

Tags: php, date, datetime, doctrine, query-builder

I am trying to filter results from my entity in question by start/end date. I have dates that I am passing in my database by fields startDate and endDate but I am always getting an empty response. No results.

```
 public function getResults(\DateTime $startDate, \DateTime $endDate)
{

    $result = $this->getRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('q.created BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
        ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

And I am passing trough my controller date ranges that I have in a database to test it:

```
$this->container->get('app')->getResults(new \DateTime('2019-03-01'), new \DateTime('2019-03-03'));
```

Comment: it's weard that you use q.id in query. it should be smth with datetime-column: q.created for example. table structure is required :)

Comment: I edited my post because I am actually trying with created. :) @myxaxa

Comment: you can get you native sql query for debug purpose: ...->getQuery()->getSql() and check what's going on. everything looks fine for me

Comment: None error in question. It just returns empty results.  @myxaxa

Comment: yeah, I understood:) it return result of the query. you need to debug query with your data - maybe it's okay that result is empty. is there any result if the `where` statement is removed?